# Pandas merge with "left" option is losing rows in left data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have 2 dataframes.
The first (left) dataframe has 5,000,000 rows, second has only 47,000 rows.
When I try to merge these dataframes with "left" option I get only 47.000 rows.

```
first = pd.read_csv('first.csv')
second = pd.DataFrame(first['id'])
second.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
second['mark'] = second['id'].apply(lambda x:get_mark(x))
new=first.merge(second,how='left',on='id')
```

here I get 47,000 raws.

Reopen the first dataframe.

```
first = pd.read_csv('first.csv')
new=first.merge(second,how='left',on='id')
```

Here I get 5,000,000 raws with marks.

How can I avoid reloading the first dataframe or fix this problem?

Comment: can you provide a link to datasets? You can remove sensitive data if needed. Also provide the full code (read, index setting, shape, merge, etc)

Comment: Unfortunately, all data is sensitive(customer logs), so I can not give access to data.
I've added all code to the main post.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with code, so you need to look into the data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sys


print('python version ', sys.version)
def get_mark(x):
    # just random data
    return np.random.normal(x, 2) 

# Simulate data
first_series = np.random.randint(0, 47000, 5000000)
first = pd.DataFrame(first_series, columns=['id'])

second = pd.DataFrame(first['id'])
second.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
second['mark'] = second['id'].apply(lambda x:get_mark(x))

print('Shape first', first.shape)
print('Shape second', second.shape)

# merge
new=first.merge(second,how='left',on='id')


print('Shape new',  new.shape)
```

```
python version  3.8.5 (tags/v3.8.5:580fbb0, Jul 20 2020, 15:57:54) [MSC v.1924 64 bit (AMD64)]
Shape first (5000000, 1)
Shape second (47000, 2)
Shape new (5000000, 2)
```